# how to use unity-scope-sshsearch?

Tags: unity, ssh, unity-dash, 13.10, lenses

I used `unity-lens-sshsearch` on 12.04, 12.10 and 13.04. But after upgrading to 13.10 it's not working any more. (<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> does nothing)

As the lens package is not available on 13.10 I installed `unity-scope-sshsearch` (successor of the lens?) but do not get any results in the dash for query's like user@host, hostname, 192.168... and so on.

My `~/.ssh/config` look's like this:

```
Host user@hostname
Hostname 192.168.1.1
User user
```

Already tried it with a newly created user, still no results.

How is `unity-scope-sshsearch` intended to work?

Answer (score 0):

It is meant to list results under the **Boxes** category and does not have a shortcut key to search explicitly for connections any more. It (at least for me) is not working in this manner either.